# Python to End a phone call

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I am trying to make a program using Python and SL4A for my android phone and it should make or recieve a phone call and wait some time then the phone should end the call.

With SL4A I was not able to find a method to end the call... But is there a SL4A way to do it?

If not, what should I do?

Thank You!

Comment: maybe pyjnius will be useful http://pyjnius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android.html#android

Comment: you could pass an "intent" to Android. https://www.google.com/search?q=android+intent+end+call